# How to import python script from submodule?

Tags: python, import, module, pycharm, python-module

I have a following structure of python modules:

```
/foo.py
/module
/module/__init__.py
/module/submodule/__init__.py
/module/submodule/bar.py
```

in foo.py I have the following code:

```
from module.submodule.bar import *
```

But as the result I'm getting the following error:

```
'.../module/bar.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Why python is trying to find the file at /module/bar.py but not module/submodule/bar as I stated in import?

Comment: Works for me. Do you have something odd in one of the `__init__.py` files?

Comment: That's not an error you get from importing. Seems like you have some code that does `open(something)` either in `bar.py` or one of the `__init__.py` files.

Comment: Yeah... it was a very strange behaviour from PyCharm after  refactoring. Recreation of Run Configuration has solved the problem. Thanks everyone, you gave me an idea try to run it from console, and it worked.

Comment: @infalco, when the self-answer timer expires, please post that as an answer below and accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was an error of PyCharm. If you're moving your script from one folder to another it saves the old path and working with it, even if you're changed it in Run config. So recreation of Run config solves the issue.